# UIwebview listen to javascript events

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I know that there are a lot of answers available in this context but none of them fits in the situation for me.

The HTML file that I am working on is a SPA. Now the problem is that the links created in the nav element are not actually links so the webview:shouldstartloadwithrequest is called just once while loading the file in UIWebview.

What I need to do is to capture the event that is generated, manipulate the object and re trigger the same event.

Is there a way to do so like capturing the event in Objective C code and accordingly retrigger the event using the event object.

Moreover I have added a single tap gesture to check for the touches that are taking place in UIWebView.

I even tried the approach to get the touch point but that is not going to solve the purpose.

Here is the HTML Code.

```
<nav id='nav-top'>
    <ul>
        <li id="btn-0" class="button"></li>
        <li id="btn-1" class="button active"></li>
        <li id="btn-2" class="button"></li>
        <li id="btn-3" class="button"></li>
        <li id="btn-4" class="button"></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The events and page transitions are handled using javascript.

Is there anyway that I can do this kind of trick ?